# R: two scatterplots on single graph using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please note I am beginner with R.
I have merged two data frames with one common column with merge() method. I have obtained data frame like:

```
 x   y1   y2
 1   3    5
 2   2    4
 1   2    2
 3   5    5
 ...
```

etc.
i would like to plot such data frame with ggplot. What I have created (using documention of [geom_point](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/ggplot2/html/geom_point.html) is

```
ggplot(data = dat_c, aes(games, variance.x)) + 
     geom_point(aes(x = games, y = variance.x), legend=  TRUE,  xlab="X", ylab="Y", colour=alpha('red', 0.05)) + 
     geom_point(aes(x = games, y = variance.y), legend = TRUE, colour=alpha('blue', 0.05) )
```

It works, NaNs do not disturb me because I get warning that they are ignored, which is fine. However I have two problems and I am not sure how to fix them:

1. my actual plot is located at the bottom-left corner, I would like to set max values for X and Y axis (in a dynamic manner, for example with highest value from data + 100 or something like this)
2. the legend is not displayed
3. the axis are not described

Here is how it looks hlike: 
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See also:

- [Plot multiple variables on y-axis using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411749/plot-multiple-variables-on-y-axis-using-ggplot)
- [R - creating legend for three data sets on same graph using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861489/r-creating-legend-for-three-data-sets-on-same-graph-using-ggplot)
- [How to manually add a legend to a ggplot object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581698/how-to-manually-add-a-legend-to-a-ggplot-object)
- [ggplot and R: Two variables over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427457/ggplot-and-r-two-variables-over-time)

(these are the results of searching `[r] ggplot melt`, although you might also have gotten there via `[r] ggplot legend` ...)

If you can, get a copy of the `ggplot` book and read it from the beginning -- unfortunately the PDF of the draft is no longer available online, but the book is worth the investment.

1. You actually have some points with `x` and `y` values near the extremes of your plot.  It's just hard to see them because they're nearly transparent (it will be a little easier to see them on a white background, i.e. try adding `+theme_bw()` to your `ggplot` call).  You can use `xlim` and `ylim` if you want to restrict the range of the plot.  (Try `summary` on your data and check out the Max values ...)
2. the best way to get the axes drawn is to follow the `ggplot` idiom of "melting" your data into a long-format data set with one column for the category (`y1` vs `y2`) and another for the value, as follows:

---

```
  d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,1,3),
                y1=c(3,2,2,5),
                y2=c(5,4,2,5))
  library(ggplot2) 
  library(reshape2) ## for melt()
  dm  <- melt(d,id.var=1)
  ggplot(data=dm,aes(x,value,colour=variable))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.2)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
  labs(x="games",y="variance")
```

(sorry for the slightly odd formatting)
I set the `alpha` value a little higher because otherwise it would have been hard to see the points in the figure.  I think the default colours (reddish and blue-ish) are OK, but I used `scale_colour_manual` to get them the way you specified.
[image]

3. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. The last point was just about labels for X and Y axis - you have covered it by labs() method, which I did not know (I tried xlab and ylab).

Comment: OK.  It should also work if you do `+xlab("games")+ylab("variance")` (as separate terms in the ggplot object, not within the `geom_point()` call ...)

Comment: @BenBolker does `scale_colour_manual` have the named argument `value`? It seems to me it is `values`, with the final 's'.

Answer (score 9):

You should `melt` your data into long format and then map the colour aesthetic to the variable column from the melted data.frame. Something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,1,3), y1 = c(3,2,2,5), y2 = c(5,4,2,5))

dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "x")

ggplot(dat.m, aes(x, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

You can manually set the limits with `xlim()` and `ylim()` respectively. It's not clear what you're doing with alpha, so I'll leave that one up to you.