# two scatterplots in ggplot with arrows between the two scatterplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that it is possible to [put two scatterplots onto one plot in `ggplot2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192478/r-two-scatterplots-on-single-graph-using-ggplot), but I also need to put an arrow between the relevant points.

For example, if I have the following `data.frame`:

```
SPEAKER <- c("A","A","B","B")
VOWEL <- c("ej","ow","ej","ow")
MB_F1_ONGLIDE <- c(423.88,533.297,465.796,532.118)
MB_F2_ONGLIDE <- c(1847.428,962.485,1815.381,1058.883)
MB_F1_OFFGLIDE <- c(404.827,480.176,423.381,522.727)
MB_F2_OFFGLIDE <- c(1885.349,911.669,1887.392,971.168)
data <- data.frame(SPEAKER,VOWEL,MB_F1_ONGLIDE,MB_F2_ONGLIDE,MB_F1_OFFGLIDE,MB_F2_OFFGLIDE)
```

I know that I can make two scatterplots appear on the same plot like this:

```
plot <- ggplot(data,aes(x = MB_F2_ONGLIDE,y = MB_F1_ONGLIDE,color = SPEAKER,label = VOWEL)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = MB_F2_ONGLIDE,y = MB_F1_ONGLIDE)) + 
    geom_text(aes(x = MB_F2_OFFGLIDE,y = MB_F1_OFFGLIDE)) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    scale_y_reverse()
```

Which produces:

[image]

But what I want is something like:

[image]

That is, I want something that draws an arrow from the `MB_F1_ONGLIDE` value to the `MB_F1_OFFGLIDE` value and something that draws an arrow from the `MB_F2_ONGLIDE` value to the `MB_F2_OFFGLIDE` value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can use `geom_segment()`, you will need to load `grid` or `gridExtra` to draw the arrow. You can tinker with line size/color in the geom_segment call, look at ?arrow for how to change the arrow shape/behaviour

```
require(gridExtra)

ggplot(data,aes(x = MB_F2_ONGLIDE,y = MB_F1_ONGLIDE,color = SPEAKER,label = VOWEL)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = MB_F2_ONGLIDE,y = MB_F1_ONGLIDE)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = MB_F2_OFFGLIDE,y = MB_F1_OFFGLIDE)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = MB_F2_ONGLIDE,y = MB_F1_ONGLIDE,xend = MB_F2_OFFGLIDE,yend = MB_F1_OFFGLIDE,color=SPEAKER),arrow=arrow()) +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]